# CoreUI Vuejs input form

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

I am using CoreUI template for VueJS version but i am not sure how to get the CInput value from this link: https://coreui.io/vue/demo/3.0-beta.1/#/forms/basic-forms,

I want to binding the input value just like this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text

Here is the code, i have used v-model but it looks like it is unable to work:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p style="white-space: preline;">{{message}}</p>
        <CForm>
              <CInput
                v-model="message"
                label="Input is valid"
                valid-feedback="Input is valid."
                invalid-feedback="Please provide at least 4 characters."
                value="Valid value"
                :is-valid="validator"
              />
              <CInput
                label="Input is invalid"
                valid-feedback="Thank you :)"
                invalid-feedback="Please provide at least 4 characters."
                :is-valid="validator"
              />
            </CForm>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        validator(val) {
            return val ? val.length >= 4 : false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-model` isn't available with `CInput` component. According to their [docs](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/form-components.html#cinput-and-ctextarea-api), you can use the events (`update:value`, `input` and `change`) to update your component data. Example:

```
<template>
<div>
    <p style="white-space: preline;">{{message}}</p>
    <CForm>
          <CInput
            label="Input is valid"
            valid-feedback="Input is valid."
            invalid-feedback="Please provide at least 4 characters."
            :value="message"
            @input="message = $event.target.value"
            :is-valid="validator"
          />
          <CInput
            label="Input is invalid"
            valid-feedback="Thank you :)"
            invalid-feedback="Please provide at least 4 characters."
            :is-valid="validator"
          />
        </CForm>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        message: "",
      }
    },
    methods: {
        validator(val) {
            return val ? val.length >= 4 : false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @input="message = $event.target.value", in my case target was returning itself the value of the input. I don't know if it's a thing about newer versions or it's already a bug in your example. Thanks anyway for the tip, I find CoreUI for Vue docs very poor in this case

Comment: Well I used `v-model` for input in my code and works fine. Please review and edit. TNX